# Best practice to implement the actual blue/green deployment for serverless application created by cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, blue-green-deployment

**[background]**
Hi, I'm preparing to implement serverless application using cloudformation(aws-sam) and would like to apply blue/green deployment for production environment.
This application is actually small and has only API gateway, Lambda, S3, Statemachine, and events(I mean no database inside), and we don't need to automate whole process of the deployment.
And I will take the approach to switch from blue to green by switching Base Path Mapping in Custom Domain Name.

**[question]**
I would like to know the practical way to deploy using blue/green approach.
my option is -

- Create exactly the same two environment named Stack-blue and Stack-green. every time I deploy, I reuse/update either older stack and switch.
- When I deploy, I always create totally new stack named Stack-20191220 putting deploy date for example. and after all deployment done, delete the older stack.

The concept of the deployment is the same but which are you using? (reuse or newly create and discard older one.)

Answer (score 0):

Following the same approach for B/G.

- Essentially all the stacks are post-fixed with Blue/Green across all
  stages.
- At one point of time both the Blue/Green stack can be
  active. Once the validation is complete the Old stack is removed. All
  the traffic is moved to new Blue/Green Stack

This does create an overhead of managing permissions/roles for two different stacks. But it keeps the deployment isolated and business can deploy/validate/roolback application at will.